Parse Date in flattened JSON based on condition
Although I got a solution for parsing dates within Jolt (thanks to Barbaros Özhan),
I am currently stuck with the following JSON:
{
  "units.1021298.attributes[0].erp_lastchange_by.identifier": "erp_lastchange_by",
  "units.1021298.attributes[0].erp_lastchange_by.attributeDataType": "PLAIN_STRING",
  "units.1021298.attributes[0].erp_lastchange_by.values[0].value": "name4711",
  "units.1021298.attributes[1].endtime.identifier": "endtime",
  "units.1021298.attributes[1].endtime.attributeDataType": "DATEANDTIME",
  "units.1021298.attributes[1].endtime.values[0].value": "15.07.2024 08:54:39",
  "units.1021298.attributes[2].country_of_origin.identifier": "country_of_origin",
  "units.1021298.attributes[2].country_of_origin.attributeDataType": "PLAIN_STRING",
  "units.1021298.attributes[2].country_of_origin.values[0].value": "DE",
  "units.1021298.attributes[3].standards.identifier": "standards",
  "units.1021298.attributes[3].standards.attributeDataType": "PLAIN_STRING",
  "units.1021298.attributes[3].standards.values[0].value": "my standard",
  "units.1021298.attributes[4].starttime.identifier": "starttime",
  "units.1021298.attributes[4].starttime.attributeDataType": "DATEANDTIME",
  "units.1021298.attributes[4].starttime.values[0].value": "02.07.2024"
  }

And this desired output:
{
  "units.1021298.attributes[0].erp_lastchange_by.identifier": "erp_lastchange_by",
  "units.1021298.attributes[0].erp_lastchange_by.attributeDataType": "PLAIN_STRING",
  "units.1021298.attributes[0].erp_lastchange_by.values[0].value": "name4711",
  "units.1021298.attributes[1].endtime.identifier": "endtime",
  "units.1021298.attributes[1].endtime.attributeDataType": "DATEANDTIME",
  "units.1021298.attributes[1].endtime.values[0].value": "2024-07-15'T'08:54:39",
  "units.1021298.attributes[2].country_of_origin.identifier": "country_of_origin",
  "units.1021298.attributes[2].country_of_origin.attributeDataType": "PLAIN_STRING",
  "units.1021298.attributes[2].country_of_origin.values[0].value": "DE",
  "units.1021298.attributes[3].standards.identifier": "standards",
  "units.1021298.attributes[3].standards.attributeDataType": "PLAIN_STRING",
  "units.1021298.attributes[3].standards.values[0].value": "my standard",
  "units.1021298.attributes[4].starttime.identifier": "starttime",
  "units.1021298.attributes[4].starttime.attributeDataType": "DATEANDTIME",
  "units.1021298.attributes[4].starttime.values[0].value": "2024-07-02"
  }

Dates should be transformed to ISO data only when the corresponding object has an attributeDataType of DATEANDTIME. (in this case: object 1 and 4). The names of the keys might differ (the part after the fist and the third dot; the rest of the structure remains the same).

This time, you should separate the attributes with the keys of type ....time....value through nesting them by those key values such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "*time*value": "&.&"//nesting mentioned occurs here
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*time*value": {
        "day_": "=substring(@(1,&1),0,2)",
        "mon_": "=substring(@(1,&1),3,5)",
        "year_": "=substring(@(1,&1),6,10)",
        "time_": "=substring(@(1,&1),11,19)",
        "value": "=concat(@(1,year_),'-',@(1,mon_),'-',@(1,day_))"
      }
    }
  },
  { //adhere 'T' through checking existence of the attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*time*value": {
        "time_?": "=concat(''T'',@(1,&))", // occurs only if the "time_" attribute exists
        "value": "=concat(@(1,&),@(1,time_))"
      }
    }
  },
  { //match the time attribute values with object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "*time*value": {
        "value": "&1"
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :


Hello Barbaros Özhan,
Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I can't rely on the fact that there will always be a "time" substring in the key. The identifiers can also have different names and still have a timestamp as  value. My only indicator is the attributeDataType: "DATEANDTIME" within the same array Object.
